# OpenCV: Searching for pixels along single-pixel branches

Tags: opencv

I'm currently trying to find a neat way of storing separate "branches" in a binary image. This little animation explains it:

[image: searching for branches]

As I go along the branches I need to collect the pixel indices that makes up a single-pixel wide branch. When I hit a junction point it should split up and store the new branches.

One way of going about it is maybe to create a 3x3 subregion, find out if there are white pixels inside it, move it accordingly, create a junction point if there is more than two. Always store the previous subregion so one can use it for making sure that we don't move to regions we already scanned.
It's a bit tricky to figure out how I would go about it though.

I basically need to reorder the pixels based on a "line/curve" hierarchy. Another part of the application will then redraw the figures, which internally works by creating lines between points hence the need to have them "ordered".

Comment: this looks like a [graph traversal problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal), where junction points are nodes and single pixel wide branches are the edges of the graph. Starting from an arbitrary initial point, you can discover all the branches and junctions by applying graph traversal algorithms like [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

Comment: Also, you may look into [Connected Components Labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)

Comment: @pray Do you need to make a search here? Is it a constraint to start from and move along a branch? If you can "see" the whole image, it is easier to group and label the branches. If you cannot, then you need a depth first search and move back to the junction to search another one; store the datas everytime  -as Alexey suggested right now.

Comment: I can see the whole image, the problem is the need to reorder the pixels. The input is handwritten text, which needs to be translated as a set of of points (per character/number etc) that later needs to be redrawn (not by OpenCV). The part that handles the redrawing requires it to be a set of points where it draws lines between points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you could apply it in your case but you should take a look at cv::findContour.
you will get a vector of points ordered.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

Comment: Ah, tried that. findContours does not play along nicely with single-pixel lines. It is also not really suitable for what I want to do later with the data.

Comment: I'm an idiot. This method does work, specially with the thinning applied beforehand.